# How do I get rid of attribute Error when running fuzzywuzzy?

Tags: python, string, attributeerror, levenshtein-distance, fuzzywuzzy

I'm trying to compare 2 lists and get a distance ratio for each item on the list. My code below returned an attribute error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'fuzz'. How do i fix this?

'differences' is a result from my earlier code for a list of companies with actual comparison (exact match) and df['Company'] is a column in my dataframe i'm trying to compare with.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
str1 = ['differences']
str2 = df['Company']
print ("distance {} -> {}: {}".format(str1,str2.fuzz.ratio(str1,str2)))
```

Comment: You are using str2.fuzz.ratio() instead of str2, fuzz.ratio()

Comment: 2nd, this code wont return you fuzz ratio() for each element

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = ['differences']
str2 = ['abcd','differ']
for x in str1:
    for y in str2:
          print ("distance {} -> {}: {}".format(x,y,fuzz.ratio(x,y)))
```

[image]

Replace str2 with df['Company']

Comment: just tried this and it doesn't work still. Just to clarify, ['differences'] and df['Company'] are a list of items and i'm trying to compare item A in 'differences' list with item A in the column df['Company'] and looping it for B,C,D....Z. Hope this clarifies my original question

Comment: ['differences'] is a list of 1 element or is differences some other list you have put in inverted commas? Also, can you show me the error/output after running this code block

Comment: 'differences' is a list of 60 elements. 
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Comment: so do you wish to match each element of differences to each element of df['Company']. Hence if differences has 60 elements  & df['company'] has 60 elements, than a total of 3600 comparisons? or you want element wise matching. Like 1st element of differences to match with 1st element of df['company'] producing 60 results

Comment: Ah i see the problem with what i'm trying to do now. Both lists are not arranged in any order. 'differences' is the shorter list and df['company] is the master list. I'd like each element in 'differences' to be compared with the closest matching element in df'[company] and obtain a ratio from it. This was i can filter out more close matches. I'm after the difference (ie element in difference list not in df['companies'] list

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments it appears you would like to iterate over a list and would like to find the closest match in a pandas Series. This answer is using [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz), since it is faster than fuzzywuzzy, but would work pretty much the same way with fuzzywuzzy. To find the closest match in an iterable you can use `process.extractOne`, which will return a tuple `(match, score)` for a normal list, or a tuple `(match, score, key)` for objects that provide a `.items()` functions like e.g. a `dict` or a `pandas.Series`.

```
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz

short_list = ['differences']
companies = df['Company']
for x in short_list:
  match = process.extractOne(x, companies, scorer=fuzz.ratio, processor=None)
  print("best match for {} is {} with a score of {} at the index {}"
    .format(x, match[0], match[1], match[2]))
```